# Responsive/Fluid Views for Responsive/Fluid Website

Tags: views, 7, entities

I an creating a Responsive/Fluid website with Drupal. Everything is great, expect when I create a view with the view module, I cannot the view to become responsive/fluid like other images I have on the site.

What I have tried is to make the .views-field-field-images width 100%, which should make the image with in views responsive. However no luck!

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a responsive base theme? If not, try a responsive theme like Omega. It is also possible that the order in which your CSS files being loaded, was set in a way that the base theme (assuming non responsive), overwrote what you have written. Make user that when you do drupal_add_css, you use proper weight and group value, to manage their load order.